# CoordinatorLayout, FAB and container layout conflict

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I have a main activity with a drawer that have a `container layout` where I replace each fragment with `FragmentManager`.

I want to add a FAB to one of my child fragments that *hide/show* on scroll but Im not sure what Im doing wrong and get:

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
      android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
      android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_little"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Just increase the bottom margin and it looks fine.

Comment: You can also put the FAB block in <RelativeLayout>FAB BLOCK </RelativeLayout> and set alignParentBottom = true and alignParentRight=true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Looks like `CoordinatorLayout` cant handle behaviour of children views that are not *"direct children"*.
2. You need to add a `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"` and `android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"` in your fab view.

For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_feeds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_white"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

Comment: Yeah but the margin is the one that make it appear

Comment: but you have add app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" line?

Comment: yeah, I used and set anchor to the `FrameLayout` or the `RecyclerView` but no results

Comment: use the anchor just in FAB view, framelayout or recyclerview use just app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Note: right | end is the same as end because end includes the same positive bits as right.

Answer (score 2):

add `app:layout_anchor="@id/container"` to your FAB. Also, by indicating `bottom|right` there is no need to include `end`

Comment: what about this case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330651/fragment-layout-with-fab-conflict-with-coordinatorlayout

Comment: The Floating Action Button is defined within the Fragment itself there, as a member of that ViewGroup, it will obey the scrolling of the parent it is nested in - rather than the Activity

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code

```
public class FABBehaviour extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public FABBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);

        //child -> Floating Action Button
        if (dyConsumed > 0) {
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            int fab_bottomMargin = layoutParams.bottomMargin;
            child.animate().translationY(child.getHeight() + fab_bottomMargin).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
            child.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    } }
```

in Xml

```
app:layout_behavior="Your PpackageName.FABBehaviour"
```

Comment: This dont solve the issue but is a cool animation, I prefer to use `child.hide()` and `child.show()` :).