# Floating Button is not Floating in android studio, so what should I do?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Xml part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TheMain">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
       
    // For example:
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
        android:onClick="AddExpense"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am using scroll view.
I've tried using more than one layout but nothing helped.
IF you can help, please help.
It is stuck.
It took a part of the layout.

Comment: you might run into the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985391/floating-action-button-at-the-end-of-a-coordinatorlayout